# counting techniques with poker

Tags: probability, statistics

Two cards are fixedly selected from a standard deck of 52 playing cards.

The first card is replaced before the second card is selected.

Determine the probability that the denominations of the two cards match.

Answer (score 0):

Where "denominations" means the number on the card, since this is with replacement, it is very much like the question of what is the probability that if you roll two dice that the dice match.

Pick the first card.  It doesn't matter what card it was specifically.

Pick the second card.  What is the chance that the second card was the same number as the first?  Well, there are 13 different numbers, each of which are equally likely to get, and only one of them is going to be the same as the first card's number.  Therefore, the probability is $\frac{1}{13}$.

---

If you aren't convinced by the easy approach outlined above, then consider the longer and more cumbersome method of considering all possibilities.  Let $S$ be our sample space of all possible ways to draw two cards in succession with replacement.  As there are $52$ cards in the deck, there are $52\cdot 52$ outcomes in the sample space, so $|S|=52\cdot 52$.

Let $E$ be the event that the two numbers match.  To find $|E|$, approach it via multiplication principle.  By multiplication principle, first pick the number, $13$ ways.  Then pick the suit of the first card,  $4$ ways.  Finally pick the suit for the second card, $4$ ways.  Thus $|E|=13\cdot 4\cdot 4$

By definition with equiprobable outcomes, $Pr(E):=\frac{|E|}{|S|}=\frac{13\cdot 4\cdot 4}{52\cdot 52} = \frac{1}{13}$

Comment: thanks I like the second one more,easier to apply to what I'm trying to learn.